# ServiceStack Trying to create my own OpenIdOAuthProvider but VS 2017 says assembly 5.0.0.0 missing

Tags: servicestack, openid, identityserver4, openid-provider

Trying to create my own custom OpenId Auth provider, which will point to an IdentityServer service, but can't seem to find OpenIdOAuthProvider in the ServiceStack assembly.

VS 2017 says

Error   CS0012  The type 'OAuthProvider' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587'

```
public class MyCustomOpenIdOAuthProvider : ServiceStack.Authentication.OpenId.OpenIdOAuthProvider
    {
        //code goes here to point to IdentityServer Realm...
    }
```

I do have ServiceStack 5.4.1 and ServiceStack.Authentication.OpenId referenced of course.  .Net Core 2.2

Any help appreciated here.

Answer (score 1):

The [ServiceStack.Authentication.OpenId](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Authentication.OpenId) package is .NET Framework only project that's [not supported in .NET Core](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#servicestack-features-that-wont-be-supported-in-net-core) due to [OpenIdOAuthProvider.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Authentication.OpenId/OpenIdOAuthProvider.cs) requiring DotNetOpenAuth which is not available for .NET Core.

As you're using the [v5.4.1 pre-release MyGet packages](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) you may be interested in the new [NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/use-existing-asp-net-core-identity-to-validate-ss-api/6599/2?u=mythz) which provides an adapter which maps an Authenticated .NET Core Identity user to an authenticated ServiceStack User Session.

So if you authenticate your .NET Core App to with IdentityServer then the authenticated user should map to an Authenticated UserSession when accessing ServiceStack Services.

#### SS API Example

I have a few notes after looking into your [example on GitHub](https://github.com/richardbartley/SSApi). Basically since you've decided to use IdentityServer as Authentication Provider you remove all other ServiceStack AuthProviders except for `NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider`:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider(AppSettings), 
  }));
```

Which provides the adapter to convert from an Identity User `ClaimsPrincipal` to a ServiceStack Authenticated UserSession (and vice-versa).

If you're using `NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider` you should also remove the alternative `IdentityServerAuthFeature` implementation as well so you're only adopting a single solution to integrated with Identity Server Auth:

```
// this.Plugins.Add(new IdentityServerAuthFeature() // remove...
```

As the Identity Server uses JWT to populate the `ClaimsPrincipal` User it doesn't use `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` to indicate what to use for the Session Id. JWT's typically have a ["sub" Claim](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2) to identify the principal that is the subject of the JWT which is populated in ServiceStack's `AuthUserSession.Id` and the `AuthUserSession.Type` will be populated with "sub" to indicate the Type of Authenticated Session and that the JWT's sub (typically the Users Id) is used in the Session `Id`.

You'll be able to use the default `NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider` configuration to authenticate with Identity Server JWTs that authenticates a User as done in [your first call](https://github.com/richardbartley/SSApi/blob/1b7c71c713c5aedd5300e1dacb0c7c9d36316ac9/DemoIdSvrClient/Program.cs#L50) in `RequestTokenAsync_CallResourceOwnerFlow()`:

```
var response = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
{
    Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

    ClientId = "roclient",
    ClientSecret = "secret",

    UserName = "bob",
    Password = "password",

    Scope = "apiMB openid",
});
```

Which you can verify by decoding the JWT in jwt.io, here's the payload of an [example token I got from this request](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ijg4NDMyYTgyNDQzZDE5ODU3YjYzMmVmNzI0NTUyZDQ4IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1NDUxNzA0MjUsImV4cCI6MTU0NTE3NDAyNSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo2NTA0OCIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjY1MDQ4L3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImFwaU1CIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6InJvY2xpZW50Iiwic3ViIjoiMiIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTU0NTE3MDQyNSwiaWRwIjoibG9jYWwiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJvcGVuaWQiLCJhcGlNQiJdLCJhbXIiOlsicHdkIl19.bY5f_sYLZy8EA3ygo_rVWO1Y4zWqdK7rA0hE2iTa0HY):

```
{
  "nbf": 1545170425,
  "exp": 1545174025,
  "iss": "http://127.0.0.1:65048",
  "aud": [
    "http://127.0.0.1:65048/resources",
    "apiMB"
  ],
  "client_id": "roclient",
  "sub": "2",
  "auth_time": 1545170425,
  "idp": "local",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "apiMB"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

Which we can see contains the "sub" of **"2"** which is [Bob's UserId](https://github.com/richardbartley/SSApi/blob/1b7c71c713c5aedd5300e1dacb0c7c9d36316ac9/MbIdSvrHost/Config.cs#L143-L149):

```
new TestUser
{
    SubjectId = "2",
    Username = "bob",
    Password = "password",
    IsActive = true
}
```

Your [2nd Authentication Request](https://github.com/richardbartley/SSApi/blob/8c7460386d44df822b45f081f0f9071e5601043f/DemoIdSvrClient/Program.cs#L92) is an example of authenticating a client:

```
var response = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
{
    Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

    ClientId = "client",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    Scope = "apiMB"
});
```

Which [doesn't contain a subject in its JWT](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ijg4NDMyYTgyNDQzZDE5ODU3YjYzMmVmNzI0NTUyZDQ4IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1NDUxNzA5MTQsImV4cCI6MTU0NTE3NDUxNCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo2NTA0OCIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjY1MDQ4L3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImFwaU1CIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImNsaWVudCIsInNjb3BlIjpbImFwaU1CIl19.bxOq1IVfAJuSrTa2PajzFjcTX_BwZwtZ20UJodo6tU0) but instead is only populated with:

```
{
  "nbf": 1545170914,
  "exp": 1545174514,
  "iss": "http://127.0.0.1:65048",
  "aud": [
    "http://127.0.0.1:65048/resources",
    "apiMB"
  ],
  "client_id": "client",
  "scope": [
    "apiMB"
  ]
}
```

In this case ServiceStack with authenticate it as a client where `AuthUserSession.Type` will be populated with `client_id` and the session `Id` will be populated with `client`.

By default ServiceStack allows authenticating with any Authenticated `client_id` (which is validated by Identity Server before it reaches ServiceStack). If you instead only want to restrict a subset of client applications to be able to access ServiceStack Services you can specify them in `RestrictToClientIds`, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider(AppSettings) {
            RestrictToClientIds = new List<string> { "client" },
        }, 
  }));
```

Where ServiceStack will only allow access from client applications with the `client` client_id.

The Audiences (aud) of the JWT are populated in AuthUserSession's `Audiences` whilst the JWT scopes are populated in `Scopes` property, whilst all other un-mached properties from the JWT in the sessions `Meta` dictionary.

These changes in `NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider` are only available in the [latest v5.4.1 on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget). If you already had v5.4.1 you'll need to clear your NuGet cache to fetch the latest v5.4.1 from MyGet:

```
$ nuget locals all -clear
```

#### Code Review Issues

Not related to Authentication but I noticed a few issues in your code where to read the AppSettings from your App you should just use the `AppSettings` property instead of creating a new instance:

```
// var appSettings = new AppSettings(); // Use base.AppSettings instead
```

You can also access .NET Core's `IConfiguration` with:

```
var configuration = ((NetCoreAppSettings) AppSettings).Configuration;
```

Instead of trying to re-create it with:

```
//IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
//       .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
//       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
//       .Build();
```

Comment: Thanks.  Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong but I can get a normal api secure and the [Authorize] attribute to work, but trying to hook ServiceStack up with it just keeps giving me Unauthorized.

Comment: @richardb If you can put together a small stand-alone App on GitHub showing the issue I can take a look.

Comment: Appreciate that - I'll see what I can do.  Not sure how the PlugIn should look for that NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider.  In the meantime I've also tried the IdentityServerAuthFeature but no joy there.

Comment: @richardb here's an [example registration of NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/b2c49a900f54670a49f7495b971c2701ba862e4f/tests/CheckMvcIdentityCore/Startup.cs#L171) added to a a default MVC + EF Store app, the `PopulateSessionFilter` shows an example of populating the SS AuthUserSession from roles persisted in the EF Store. You'll need to raise any issues with `IdentityServerAuthFeature` to the [relevant project](https://github.com/wwwlicious/servicestack-authentication-identityserver) which is a community created/supported project.

Comment: Demo repo here showing what I'm trying / failing to achieve. Appreciate any assistance. https://github.com/richardbartley/SSApi

Comment: Ok that is an awesome answer and its working.  Thanks for that. About to kick off an important project and we will be getting a subscription for this.  Thanks again.

Comment: @richardb glad to hear it! BTW I've updated the answer with the recent changes with support for Client App `client_id` JWT's so you don't need a special mapping and can just use the default `new NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider(AppSettings)`.